# Akka round-robin: Sending response from remote routees to sender

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster, akka-remote-actor, akka-remoting

I am using Akka Cluster (version 2.4.10) with few nodes designated for "front-end" role and few others as "workers". The workers are on remote machines. The incoming work is distributed by the front-end actor to workers by round-robin routing. The issue is sending back the response from the "workers" back to the front-end actor. I can see that the work is getting completed by the workers. But the message sent by the workers to front-end does not reach and ends up as dead-letters. I see the below error in the log.

```
[Cluster-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-21] [akka://Cluster/deadLetters] Message [scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon] from Actor[akka://Cluster/user] to Actor[akka://Cluster/deadLetters] was not delivered. [6] dead letters encountered.
```

I have seen [this](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/routing.html#Senders) and I am following the same in my code. I have also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564381/akka-routing-replys-send-to-router-ends-up-as-dead-letters), but the solution suggested does not apply in this case, because I do not know the routees up-front. It comes through the configuration and it can change. The round-robin router configuration is as below.

```
akka.actor.deployment {
  /frontEnd/hm = {
    router = round-robin-group
    nr-of-instances = 5
    routees.paths = ["/user/hmWorker"]
    cluster {
      enabled = on
      use-role = backend
      allow-local-routees = on
    }
  }
}
```

The router is instantiated in front-end actor like below.

```
val router = context.actorOf(FromConfig.props(), name = "hm")
val controller = context.actorOf(Props(classOf[Controller], router))
```

The controller and the worker codes are below.

```
// Node 1 : Controller routes requests using round-robin
class Controller(router: ActorRef) extends Actor {

    val list = List("a", "b") // Assume this is a big list

    val groups = list.grouped(500)

    override def receive: Actor.Receive = {
      val futures = groups.map(grp => (router ? Message(grp)).mapTo[List[String]]))
      val future = Future.sequence(futures).map(_.flatten)
      val result = Await.result(future, 50 seconds)
      println(s"Result is $result")
    }
}

// Node 2
class Worker extends Actor {

    override def receive: Actor.Receive = {
      case Message(lst) =>
            val future: Future[List[String]] = // Do Something asynchronous
            future onComplete {
                case Success(r) => sender.!(r)(context.parent) // This message is not delivered to Controller actor.
                case Failure(th) => // Error handling
            }
    }
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `sender()` in the callback on a `Future`. By the time the callback is processed, the `sender()` is likely referring to something different than it was when you received the message.

Consider either saving the reference outside of the callback first like:

```
override def receive: Actor.Receive = {
  case Message(lst) =>
        val future: Future[List[String]] = // Do Something asynchronous
        val replyTo: ActorRef = sender()
        future onComplete {
            case Success(r) => replyTo.!(r)(context.parent) // This message is not delivered to Controller actor.
            case Failure(th) => // Error handling
        }
}
```

Or even better, use the pipe pattern:

```
import akka.pattern.pipe
override def receive: Actor.Receive = {
  case Message(lst) =>
    val future: Future[List[String]] = // Do Something asynchronous
    future.pipeTo(sender())
}
```