# Get reference of router from routee-Akka

Tags: java, akka

This question is a follow up to:
[Akka Routing: Reply's send to router ends up as dead letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564381/akka-routing-replys-send-to-router-ends-up-as-dead-letters)

I'm facing the same problem.
It is given in the answer that

"Note that different code would be needed if the routees were 
not children of the router, i.e. if they were provided when the router was created."

I want to know What is that different code and how does it work? And is there any other way to communicate with the Router other than this method?

It'd be good if exlpained with code snippets or links to projects where it is used.